# PHP: How to prevent unwanted line breaks

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I'm using PHP to create some basic HTML. The tags are always the same, but the actual links/titles correspond to PHP variables:

```
$string = '<p style="..."><a href="'.$html[$i].'"><strong><i>'.$title[$i].'</i></strong></a>
<br>';
echo $string;
fwrite($outfile, $string);
```

The resultant html, both as echoed (when I view the page source) and in the simple txt file I'm writing to, reads as follows:

```
    <p style="..."><a href="http://www.example.com
"><strong><i>Example Title
</i></strong></a></p>
<br>
```

While this works, it's not exactly what I want. It looks like PHP is adding a line break every time I interrupt the string to insert a variable. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there aren't newlines at the end of the variables you're inserting?  Try wrapping them in trim() to see if that stops it.  If it does then your variables actually contain the line breaks.

Comment: Thanks, I used <code>rtrim</code> and that fixed the problem. Since you solved it first, if you add an answer within the next 24 or so hours, I'll be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it won't affect your HTML page at all with the line breaks (unless you are using `pre` or `text-wrap: pre`), you should be able to call `trim()` on those variables to remove newlines.

To find out if your variable has a newline at front or back, try this regex

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^\n|\n$/', $variable));
```

(I think you have to use single quotes so PHP doesn't turn your `\n` into a literal newline in the string).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your variables are to blame. You might try cleaning them up with `trim`: https://www.php.net/trim.

Answer (score 0):

The line breaks show up because of multi-byte encoding, I believe.  Try:

```
$newstring =  mb_substr($string_w_line_break,[start],[length],'UTF-8');
```

That worked for me when strange line breaks showed up after parsing html.