# How to tell if a string in PHP has a newline appended or prepended?

Tags: php, regex

I just [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251983/php-how-to-prevent-unwanted-line-breaks/4251995#4251995), and was trying to come up with a regex that will return `true` if a string has a newline at the front or back.

I came up with [this](http://codepad.org/iENaNqAQ)...

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^\n|\n$/', $testVar));
```

But I get the error...

> Warning: preg_match(): Internal pcre_fullinfo() error -3 on line 5

I can't tell what I am doing wrong. To me that says *match where a newline is first character or last character*.

Please enlighten me.

Thanks.

#### Update

I realised this question title should probably be *Why does my regex not work?* or similar.

**But**, I'm going to leave it as is, and welcome alternate solutions to the regex.

Comment: It is working fine for me (it returns `int(0)` or `int(1)`)

Comment: @casablanca [I've only tested it with codepad.org](http://codepad.org/iENaNqAQ) - perhaps it is codepad.org's fault :)

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. That error indicates some error with the internal regex engine itself, and most probably not the calling code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you not take the usual string functions?

```
if ((substr($string,0,1) == "\n") || (substr($string,-1) == "\n")) {
    // found newline at the beginning or end
}
```

or just

```
if (($string[0] == "\n") || ($string[strlen($string)-1] == "\n")) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Yeah I could do that :) But I was more interested in why the regex wouldn't work, not alternatives. Thanks for your answer though. :)

Comment: As for *why not use string functions*, I thought a regex would be more compact, and easier to understand at a glance. I'm going to accept this answer for providing two alternates.

Comment: In short: Regular expressions are always very heavy. If you can solve something with usual string functions, you are strongly advised, not to use regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
trim($testVar,"\n") != $testVar
```

Comment: Does that avoid trimming whitespace that isn't newlines? I never understood how the second parameter works...

Comment: if no 2nd arg is specified, trim() removes spaces. otherwise, it strips the value represented by 2nd arg

Comment: @BoltClock Second parameter is a pool of chars I believe that is stripped. Some people (me originally) also made the mistake that it was to trim the *actual* string, not as in a pool of chars. This nearly bit me :)

Answer (score 1):

*It's not you, it's me!* You are not doing anything wrong. That is a problem with the server's php installation. I remember seeing this when I installed PHP on a debian server with apache2. I don't know exactly *why* or *what* this is, but I finally ended up reinstalling php on my server and everything was fine.

Comment: I like this answer, it actually answers me :) +1

Comment: @alex: seems like the title of this question and actual content are not in sync then

Comment: @stillstanding Sorry, yeah I guess so. In that case, I welcome all alternate solutions!